# Python 3 optimization: updating global value vs passing as parameter

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a function `funcA` that tracks the number of visitors visiting a particular website. This can be done in two ways (not worrying about concurrency at the moment):

**Approach 1**

```
def funcA (... other parameters ..., visitors):
   ..... computation ...
   visitors.append(visitor)

# initialize the function 
funcA(.... parameters, [] )
```

**Approach 2**

```
def funcA (... other parameters ...):
   ..... computation ...
   self.visitors.append(visitor)

# initialize the function 
self.visitors = []
funcA(.... parameters)
```

Both the approaches yield the same result. However, using approach 2 results in approximately 20% faster execution time than approach 1. Can someone explain? The experiment was conducted on Python 3.8 using `timeit`  module

Comment: How exactly did you benchmark this?

Comment: using python timeit module